# How to get values from a element without tag/name selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a specific field which has the price value but sometimes there are two values. For example:

The first...

```
<div ng-if="producto.precionormal!=null &amp;&amp; producto.precioreferencia==null &amp;&amp; producto.precio!=null" class="minificha__precio-referencia ng-binding ng-scope">
    <span>Precio preferente</span>
    US $44.77 Unidad
</div>
```

The second...

```
<div ng-if="producto.precionormal!=null &amp;&amp; producto.precio!=null" class="minificha__precio-preferencial ng-binding ng-scope">
    <span>Precio promoción</span>
    US $43.73 Unidad
</div>
```

Also, the values are inside element without name/tag, how I can get the second price value if two of them appear and if just one appear, just take that one. I'm trying this but I get the span/span value and both prices too.

This is the HTML for the section:

```
<h1 class="minificha__nombre-producto">
    <a href="/tiendaonline/webapp/detalle/disco-duro-externo/603" class="ng-binding">Disco duro externo Toshiba 1TB Externo Canvio Basics Black A3Retail  </a>
</h1>
<span class="minificha__sku ng-binding">
    Cód TG: TOA-226
</span>
<span class="minificha__sku ng-binding">
    Cód. PN: HDTB410XK3AA
</span>
<div ng-if="producto.stock>umbralStock" class="minificha__disponibilidad minificha__disponibilidad--ok ng-binding ng-scope" id="stockDisponible603"> + de 20 disponible </div>
<div class="minificha__iconos">
    <ul>
        <!-- ngRepeat: icon in producto.icoInferior -->
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="minificha__precios">
    <div ng-if="producto.precionormal!=null &amp;&amp; producto.precioreferencia==null &amp;&amp; producto.precio!=null" class="minificha__precio-referencia ng-binding ng-scope">
        <span>Precio preferente</span>
        US $44.77 Unidad 
    </div>
    <div ng-if="producto.precionormal!=null &amp;&amp; producto.precio!=null" class="minificha__precio-preferencial ng-binding ng-scope">
        <span>Precio promoción</span>
        US $43.73 Unidad 
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my VBA code:

```
Set products = driver.FindElementsByXPath(".//h1[@class='minificha__nombre-producto']")
For Each product In products
    product.FindElementByXPath("following::div[3]").Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both DIVs using the CSS selector `div.minificha__precios > div` and then loop through the collection, whether it's 1 or 2 elements, and print them.

```
Set productPricing = driver.FindElementsByCss("div.minificha__precios > div")
For Each price in productPricing
    Debug.Print price.Text
Loop
```

If you want to get the price or the label, you can split this by a newline and get the two parts,

1. Precio preferente or Precio promoción
2. The price

and then do whatever you want with it.

---

I don't do VBA and I can't validate this syntax but hopefully it will be close and you can at least get the concept.

Comment: I missed that they only wanted one. I guess they can always use split to separate the text and pull the part they want if only the value

Comment: @QHarr yeah but... if your `.nextSibling.Text` thing works, it would do the cleanup of the retrieved text that mine doesn't have.

Comment: Tbh I can't remember if supported and can't test so defo deleting!

Comment: I'll give a try to JeffC suggest, I'll be back with news but I think change the "set products" part, will generate issue to obtain the rest of the data, so maybe I will need to do more changes, thanks guys.

Comment: @Peter You don't have to change the `Set products` part. You can name the variable whatever you want and just use it for pricing. I've updated the code to use `productPricing` instead of `products` so it won't affect your other code.

Comment: Didn't see you suggest a new variable, sorry, that's what I mean in my last comment (I will need to do more changes), like setup a new variable, thanks for help JeffC, Im gonna test now

Comment: Hi @JeffC it works, but not for both prices, I just use the first one I get, because sometimes some products has 2 prices or 1 prices, so if I just put that value into a differents columns, sometimes will be empty spaces if there no second price.

Lets say "it works just 50%", with you suggets Im not able to use the promotion price, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying it's not working? In your question you specifically asked for the second price if it existed, otherwise just get the first price... and that's what this code does.

Comment: Nope, the code give me both prices if there exists two for one product, that's why I say it works just 50%, because I just decided to take always the first one to avoid errors

Comment: I've updated my answer to get both prices now.